# for three thousand dollars

Tags: ambiguity, adjective-phrases, postmodification

Have you ever turned down job offers?

a. Yes. If I don't like a job, I won't take it. I have turned down many job offers. As a matter of fact, yesterday, I turned **down one** for three thousand dollars a month.

b. Yes. If I don't like a job, I won't take it. I have turned down many job offers. As a matter of fact, yesterday, I turned **one down** for three thousand dollars a month.

I think (b) is saying that I got paid three thousand dollars a month in order to turn down the job! But I think it is possible that people say (b) instead of (a) if they are a bit careless.

Many thanks.

Comment: The alternative (b) is not 'careless'. It is just as acceptable as (a).

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are correct AND both of them could be parsed to mean you got paid to turn down the job.

But context is king, so both would be understood to mean the job was three thousand dollars a month.